# setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername: password: in Multipart uploading AFNEtworking 2.0

Tags: ios7, afnetworking-2

I am using the following code for multimedia uploading

```
NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (id obj in mediaArray)
    {


        NSURLRequest *request=[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"MY URL" parameters:@"MY PARAMS" constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

            [formData appendPartWithFileURL:@"MY URL" name:@"MY File Name" error:nil];


        } error:&er];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:PushuserNameAutheitcation password:PushpasswordAutheitcation persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

    }

     NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"%lu of %lu complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations)
    {
       completion(TRUE,nil,nil);
     } ];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

I want to add authorization header.How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to pass authorization header

```
NSURLMutableRequest *request = [NSURLMutableRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
NSData* authData = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username:Password"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *auth = [authData base64EncodedString];
auth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",auth];
[request setValue:auth forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

otherwise

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"Login" 
password:@"Password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
[operation setCredential:credential];
```